# Make a page unsearchable

Tags: search

I made an AJAX email page that allows the user to send a short email, and it loads a separate page showing a message similar to"Your email has been sent." Can I make that last page (the one that shows the message) unsearchable? It's just a success page, and I think it shouldn't come out in any search result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good article by Lullabot that covers this: [Hiding content from Drupal's search system](http://www.lullabot.com/articles/hiding-content-drupals-search-system).

Comment: Great article as always from Lullabot. I think I'll try it out and use the Search Restrict module to see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

If the page is not a node, then Drupal doesn't index it, and the page isn't shown in the search results.

The Drupal core modules have support for the search module for nodes, and user profiles. This means that, for example, a setting page of a module is not included in the search, because it's not a node.